# Call custom constructor when binding a map

Tags: java, spring, data-binding, collections, spring-mvc

When a list is binded I can control how the objects are instantiated (for instace invoke a constructor with several params) by using a custom ElementFactory in an AutoPopulatingList in this way:

```
public class Foo{

    private List<NestedFoo> nested = new AutoPopulatingList<NestedFoo>(new ElementFactory<NestedFoo>() {
        @Override
        public NestedFoo createElement(int index) throws ElementInstantiationException {
            return new NestedFoo(index);
        }       
    });
}
```

Is there any way to do something similar when the collection is a Map instead of a List? I mean when the form sends something like nested['fooParam'] I want to call a constructor with the fooParam when the map is 'auto-grown'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know any solution in Spring, but [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com)'s [`MapMaker`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) class lets you create a computing map:

```
ConcurrentMap<Key, Graph> graphs = new MapMaker()
   .concurrencyLevel(4)
   .softKeys()
   .weakValues()
   .maximumSize(10000)
   .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
   .makeComputingMap(
       new Function<Key, Graph>() {
         public Graph apply(Key key) {
           // this is where your values are created on demand
           return createExpensiveGraph(key);
         }
       });
```

**Reference:**

- [`MapMaker.makeComputingMap(Function<Key,Val>)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html#makeComputingMap%28com.google.common.base.Function%29)

---

BTW, [Apache Commons / Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections) has a similar feature:

[`MapUtils.lazyMap(Map, Transformer)`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/MapUtils.html#lazyMap%28java.util.Map%2C%20org.apache.commons.collections.Transformer%29)